# Why does my long formula give me a syntax error? It has something to do with ", "

Tags: excel, vba

So this macro inserts 2 columns in C and D. Then fills this formula all the way down column C.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Format_dates()

    Dim ws As worksheet
    Dim lst As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Columns("C:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("C2").Value = "START DATE"
    Range("D2").Value = "END DATE"

    Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select

    With ActiveSheet ' ("MASTER Business Events Calendar")

        lst = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

        For i = 3 To lst
            r = Cells.row
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = "=IF(ISNUMBER(B&r),B&r,DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B&r,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(B&r,CHAR(150),"-")&"-")-1))&", "&RIGHT(B&r,4)))"
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Can I not substitute variables in formulas like I do with python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the Variable from the string:

> `B&r`

Should be

```
B" & r & "
```

And all `"` should be `""`

```
ws.Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(B" & r & "),B" & r & ",DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B" & r & ",FIND(""-"",SUBSTITUTE(B" & r & ",CHAR(150),""-"")&""-"")-1))&"", ""&RIGHT(B" & r & ",4)))"
```

Another note,  You refer to `ws` but never set it.  It should be set like

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Then remove the With block.

---

That being said the loop is not needed.

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 3),ws.Cells(lst,3)).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(B3),B3,DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B3,FIND(""-"",SUBSTITUTE(B3,CHAR(150),""-"")&""-"")-1))&"", ""&RIGHT(B3,4)))"
```

The row, since it is relative, will iterate correctly

```
Option Explicit

Sub Format_dates()

    Dim ws As worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet


    ws.Columns("C:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ws.Range("C2").Value = "START DATE"
    ws.Range("D2").Value = "END DATE"

    Dim lst As Long
    lst = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 3),ws.Cells(lst,3)).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(B3),B3,DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B3,FIND(""-"",SUBSTITUTE(B3,CHAR(150),""-"")&""-"")-1))&"", ""&RIGHT(B3,4)))"


End Sub
```

Comment: Would there be a time when I need to use a for loop for entering formulas? I was learning python (since it is easier) and applied that logic to vba. And is it always relative? If I wanted absolute, I would put $ within the formula, correct?

Comment: If you are entering a formula then use the `$` to make it absolute and just apply it to the full range at once to iterate the relative portion.  Array formulas are different and are applied differently depending on use.